# Error: socket hang up in Http Request made in Node JS using request-promise causing for loop to restart

Tags: node.js, async-await, request-promise

I am trying to make an Http Request using request-promise inside a for loop. But it seems if a Http Request takes long, request-promise closes the connection.

This behavior is ok but what I am not able to grasp is the for loop starts from 0 again after the error is printed.

Below is the code

```
const rp = require('request-promise');
async function stepIterator(processingSteps, documentId) {
    var finalResult = null;
    for (var step = 0, len = processingSteps.length; step < len; step++) {
        if (step === 0 || step === 1 || step == 2 || step == 3) {
            try {
                console.log('Calling step ', step);
                let url = 'http://internal-server:8080/process';
                let collection = getCollection(documentId);
                let splitText = getSPlit(documentId);
                let outputFormat = 'xmi';
                let documentObject = await callServer(url, collection, splitText, outputFormat);
                finalResult = documentObject;
            } catch (error) {
                console.log("Error");
            }
        }
    }
    return finalResult;
}

async function callServer(url, collection, splitText, outputFormat) {
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: url,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive '
        },
        formData: {
            collection: collection,
            text: splitText,
            output: outputFormat
        }
    };
    return rp(options)
}
```

The complete error trace is as follows

> `{ RequestError: Error: socket hang up
>       at new RequestError (D:\New_Projects\new-data-access-layer\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:14:15)
>       at Request.plumbing.callback (D:\New_Projects\new-data-access-layer\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:87:29)
>       at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (D:\New_Projects\new-data-access-layer\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:46:31)
>       at self.callback (D:\New_Projects\new-data-access-layer\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
>       at Request.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Request.onRequestError (D:\New_Projects\new-data-access-layer\node_modules\request\request.js:881:8)
>       at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:182:13)
>       at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:425:9)
>       at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)   name: 'RequestError',   message: 'Error: socket hang up',   cause:
>
>   { Error: socket hang up
>          at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:322:15)
>          at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:425:23)
>          at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
>          at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
>          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' },   error:    { Error: socket hang up
>          at createHangUpError (_http_client.js:322:15)
>          at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:425:23)
>          at Socket.emit (events.js:187:15)
>          at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
>          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19) code: 'ECONNRESET' },   options:    { method: 'POST',
>        uri: 'http://internal-server:8080/process',
>        json: true,
>        headers: { Connection: 'keep-alive ' },
>        body:
>         { docSplitId: [Array],
>           _id: 5c579d84812acb17ec74ac39,
>           contentType: 'application/pdf',
>           location:
>            'C:\\Users\\newuser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\2\\report.pdf',
>           docModelVersion: '1',
>           visualMetaDataId: null,
>           categoryId: '5c52a72f6df294140c0535bc',
>           deductedInfo: null,
>           status: 'New',
>           isDeleted: false,
>           metadata: [Object],
>           detailedStatus: [Array] },
>        callback: [Function: RP$callback],
>        transform: undefined,
>        simple: true,
>        resolveWithFullResponse: false,
>        transform2xxOnly: false },   response: undefined }`

Answer (score 0):

Obviously the socket is hanging! Don't bother with http, it is a little complex. Use node unirest and it closes the data stream.

```
var unirest = require('unirest');
var req = unirest('POST', 'localhost:3200/store/artifact/metamodel')
  .attach('file', '/home/arsene/DB.ecore')
  .field('description', 'We are trying to save the metamodel')
  .field('project', '6256d72a81c4b80ccfc1768b')
  .end(function (res) { 
    if (res.error) throw new Error(res.error); 
    console.log(res.raw_body);
  });
```

Hope this helps!